# Помогите с запросом в базу

Tags: mysql, sql

Вообщем надо чтобы давало всем параметры юзерам которые есть в определённом клане.
Но у меня получается только для 1 юзера. Как сделать для всех кто в клане?

```
mysql_query('UPDATE `users` SET `str` = "'.($user['str'] + $bonus_param[$clan_altar['level']]).'",
                                `vit` = "'.($user['vit'] + $bonus_param[$clan_altar['level']]).'",
                                `def` = "'.($user['def'] + $bonus_param[$clan_altar['level']]).'" WHERE `clan` = "'.$clan['id'].'"');
```

Answer (score 0):

Для этого используйте `IN (val1,val2,...)`

```
 mysql_query('UPDATE `users` SET `str` = "'.($user['str'] + $bonus_param[$clan_altar['level']]).'",
                                `vit` = "'.($user['vit'] + $bonus_param[$clan_altar['level']]).'",
                                `def` = "'.($user['def'] + $bonus_param[$clan_altar['level']]).'" WHERE `clan` IN ('.$id_array.')');
```

`$id_array` - массив с id юзеров, просто для примера написал

Comment: Есть еще 1 проблемка, все юзерам в клане меняет парам на мои. Как сделать так чтобы плюсовало только к ихним парам, а не ставило мои парам и плюсовало

Comment: @dg_pain, по логике вещей сперва надо брать старое значение, сохранять его а потом при записи использовать с новым.

Comment: а как, я просто новичок еще не совсем всё знаю.

Comment: я, так же, не всё знаю и не смею утверждать что написанный мною вариант единственно верный. знаю только что это работает и это не трудно реализовать

Answer (score -2):

Примерно так:

```php
mysql_query('UPDATE `users` SET `str` = str + '.$bonus_param[$clan_altar['level']]).'
WHERE `clan` = "'.$clan['id'].'"');
```